# Xcode, stepping through my own code using breakpoints

Tags: xcode, debugging

Usually, this works, but in addition to my own code there a lot of machine code too, which doesn't really help me out with debugging my own program logic.

Is there a way to step through only my own code?

Comment: Look at your call stack. You are probably stepping out of your code and back into the framework code. You do realize that 99% of iOS and Cocoa-desktop programming means that your code only runs when Cocoa calls it, right?  So you can't single step through only your code, if you only want to see your code, don't single step OUT of your code, just hit run, and have enough breakpoints to keep you happy.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
First put a breakpoint where you want to start step over.After the breakpoint ,Use this button to step over through the code.The play button just runs till the next breakpoint

Answer (score -2):

You probably want to be using the `next` command or "step over" button in the debugger UI instead of `step` or "step into" to avoid stepping into each function as you debug.  You might still want to step into your own functions, of course, but `next` will let you step over framework functions instead of diving into their assembly.

Comment: This might sound stupid of me, but where is the `next` command?

Comment: If you mean the `step over` button, this is the button I'm using, where i get thrown to assembly language

Comment: Yes, `next` is the command you would type in the debugger console (debugging with either gdb or lldb) and `step over` is the tool tip for the button in Xcode's debugger UI.  If you're using that one I'm not sure how you're getting thrown into the assembly.  Do you have any symbolic breakpoints set?  Are you hitting an exception in one of the framework methods?

Comment: Nope, I' using the step over button. I'm being sent to my next line of code as well as assembly language